# How to modify current QGIS canvas from python script?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I want to zoom into the current active QGIS canvas from a standalone python script.

I tried the following but it doesn't impact the current QGIS canvas:

```
import qgis.utils
canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()
canvas.zoomIn()
```

Can I modify the QGIS app from a standalone python script (not from the QGIS Python console)? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: Purely a guess but perhaps try using `from qgis.gui import QgsMapCanvas`?

Comment: Doesn't do anything either.

Comment: what kind of standalone script? Something that inside a QGIS session?

Comment: I have a running QGIS session and independently from that a Python script (not the Python console).

Comment: Very similar question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77797/accessing-existing-instance-of-qgis-from-stand-alone-python-script?rq=1